# Shiny: how to use removeUI to dynamically remove most recently created UI from insertUI?

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app that inserts a pair of UI elements, but I would also like the user to be able to remove those pairs if they create them and do not need them:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("remove", "Remove UI"),
  actionButton("add", "Add UI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = tagList(textInput(paste0("txt", input$add),
                     "Insert some text"),
                   numericInput(paste0("num", input$add),
                                "Insert some number",
                                value = 0)
      )
    )
  })
  
  # observeEvent(input$remove, {
  #   removeUI(
  #     selector = ??
  #   )
  # })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

This creates `input$txt<#>` and `input$num<#>` where `#` is the number of times the "Add UI" action button is selected. How do I code `removeUI(selector = )` to remove the *most recent* UI pairs created. For example, if the user has clicked "Add UI" twice, there will be `input$txt1`, `input$num1`, `input$txt2`, and `input$num2`. In this instance, I would like to remove `input$txt2` **and** `input$num2`. How do I do this dynamically?

From the documentation I know I could do something like `selector = sprintf("div:has(> #txt%i)", input$add)` and that would remove the text field, but I am not sure how to do both at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will suffice.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("remove", "Remove UI"),
  actionButton("add", "Add UI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  added <- c()
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    id <- paste0('txt',input$add)
    insertUI(
      selector = "#add",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = div(textInput(paste0("txt", input$add),
                             "Insert some text"),
               numericInput(paste0("num", input$add),
                                "Insert some number",
                                value = 0),
               id = id
               )
    )
    added <<- c(added,id)  ## remove last one first
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    removeUI(
      selector = paste0('#', added[length(added)])
    )
    added <<- added[-length(added)]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```